# Advice for first steps in time domain simulations

Tags: frequency-domain, time-domain

I am reaching out because I’ll soon have to tackle signal processing questions that were so far handled by colleagues of mine. I come from the macroscopic link budget computation world in a satellite communications context, so I am used to summing powers directly, applying impairment budgets and so on to compute C/N and C/(N+I) without having ever to instanciate carriers and simulate their behaviors in the frequency or time domain.

And I am trying to cross that barrier, so my question to your community would be, what would you advice me to read or do to get practical knowledge on this, for instance to :

- capture how a signal evolves through a payload composed of filters and non-linear amplifiers
- capturing and observing the results of these non-linaerities in terms of NPR or even radiated NPR when this power is fed to an active antenna with beamforming
- Knowing when to use time domain simulation and frequency domain simulation
- And really all the basics to do so, how do we sample time, how does a sampled signal is tranformed through a given equipment and anything basic I am not thinking of

Tell me if that is not clear and thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: I'd start with Rick Lyons DSP book for signal processing, and maybe Papoulis' Circuits and Systems book (available used for cheap).